# Make "heavy" 3D pgfplot printable/reducing PDF layers

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, printing, acrobat

**td;dr:** How can I reliably reduce the number of layers in a PDF that contains `pgfplots`with lots of data point.

I have made some 3D plots using `pgfplots` which each contain *a lot* of data points. They are typeset as PDF via `standalone` and included in the main document using `graphicx`:

[image]

I went to two local copy shops to have my document (containing roughly 20 of them included via `graphicx`) printed, but was told these plots cause my document to contain "too many layers" and their printing setup to "hang". I can print it without issues from a MacBook on a rather cheap consumer Canon ink jet printer, however.

Please don't suggest manual conversion to bitmaps. If conversion is absolutely required, I need to do it with the whole document and in an automatic way. There's no time to do it manually plot-by-plot.

Please also don't suggest reducing the data. The plots do look fine, compile within reasonable time (~1 min on my machine) and I absolutely cannot touch the data anymore right now.

Heres the MWE and the sample `csv` data can be found here on [my github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrtc90/misc/master/data.dat).

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border={1.5cm 2pt 5mm 10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
%\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum}
\usepackage[partial=upright]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    pgfplots.groupplots
}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left,trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        width=7cm,
        grid=both,
        view={120}{45},
        set layers,
        every axis plot/.append style={on layer=pre main},
        every x tick scale label/.style={
            overlay,
            at={(xticklabel* cs:0.8)},
            anchor=near xticklabel,
            inner sep=8pt,
        },
        xmin=0,
        xmax=0.01,
        ymode=log,
        ytick={0.01,0.1,1,10},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=30,
        zmin=20,
        zmax=420,
        ztick={20,200,420},
        zlabel={Quantity},
        clip=false
    ]
    \addplot3[
            surf,
            opacity=0.05,
            fill opacity=0.75,
            shader=flat,
            colormap/viridis,
        ] table [
            col sep=comma,
        ] {data.dat};
    \node at (rel axis cs:0.5,0,1) [overlay,above,sloped like x axis] {Axis A};
    \node at (rel axis cs:0,0.5,1) [overlay,above,sloped like y axis] {Axis B};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** By the way, this is the how the mininimal working example is rendered in `Adobe Acrobat Reader 11.0.23` on a Windows 10 machine (please oversee the axis labels which I have changed here):

[image]

This is obviously *not* acceptable and I wonder what's wrong with my code that only `Acrobat` fails to display it correctly. Works under Ubuntu using `Eye of Gnome` or `qpdfview` as well as under OSX using `Preview`.

Comment: well you don't leave much options to us. What do they mean by layers?Then the only option is find a proper printer

Comment: I really don't know :(

Comment: Then we can't know either. This is not a well defined question

Comment: Alright then. I assumed this was not an uncommon problem.

Comment: Maybe someone with knowledge of the technical details of printing can comment on it. I know this is not a direct pgfplots problem.

Comment: If you open the PDF file generated from the plot in Acrobat you can see via the tools that every single face of the plot surface is written to its own layer. Apparently that's too much for the common printers.

Comment: I am not an expert, but what helped me sometimes in somewhat similar situations was to open the file in a pdf viewer and then print it to a pdf (or even ps). As you are saying that you can print it from your MacBook, I'd first try to use preview for that. (I have just gone through these steps and see that the file size changes when doing that, so the file is different. Unfortunately, you are not very clear about which of the acrobat tools one should use, so I could not check whether this helps.)

Comment: @marmot It's unfortunately an Acrobat Pro feature (which I do not own) located in the right panel (edit document). Printing to PDF might have helped (it certainly changes file size!), too late to tell. It seems that the job size on those commercial printers is getting too large. Will have to extend my deadline and convert to png.

Comment: You may want to consider `shader=interp`. On my system, acrobat reader displays the result fine (and much faster) although it was slow and wrong with the original report. Interestingly, xpdf fails to display the combination `shader=interp,* opacity`... that's new to me. `shader=interp` is not what you had in mind, I know. And you may also need to combine it with `\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}` in order to avoid color burning (try it, you'll see what I mean).

Comment: Actually, I am wondering why acrobat reader applies the stroke opacity to the boundaries of the `flat` rectangles. Is this a bug in pgfplots? I added `\let\pgfplotsplothandlermeshusepathfillstroke=\pgfplotsplothandlermeshusepathfill` experimentally and the display is fine. Perhaps this would also fix the printing issue?